# Modern contribution to Scriptures

Tags: vedas, advaita

I would like to find out what, modern contribution to Hindu scriptures are? Something akin to Brahmagupta or those insights of great Rishis. Today, we are not endowed with ‘aparushya’ visions. However we are endowed with other gifts such as critical thinking.
Besides writing commentaries on existing work or hymns how is the core knowledge expanded through research? . I see so many institutions vying to teach what is in the scriptures- poor job at that, let me add. Singing and dancing in bhakthi and doing your nitya karma and belief is one thing but researching in-depth through analysis( not Sanskrit language) on the concepts is super important. If you say I will only follow Madhva or Kashmiri Shaivism teachings and read and write only about them, isn’t that a very narrow mind set? Or Oh yeah Krishna is my God, but I’ll never justify basic intelligence that I am endowed with and continue to be blinded by emotions is a dishonor to Him and his design don’t you think?